# Triggering an event when user clicks "< Back" button

Tags: ios, ios7, rubymotion

I have fairly simple `UINavigationControllers` with two screens: screen1 & screen2.

When the user is on `screen2` and clicks `< Back` I want to trigger an event before `screen1` is shown -- basically I want to fetch data from the server for screen1.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` do this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_back.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBarButton;
```

Implement the method `goBack`:

```
- (void)goBack:(id)sender {
    //Do something
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard, you can handle your back action in.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Answer (score 0):

Only by doing it in `viewWillDisappear`. Unfortunately it will be triggered also when you present a new screen over the current one, not just when you tap the back button. You could however add a custom back button, and place your code in it's action method. After the operation is finished, call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if (![self.navigationController.viewControllers containsObject:self]) {
        NSLog(@"Back Event");
    }
}
```

You can do in two way.

1. Create custom button and set event.
2. Check on viewWillDisappear when users pop the screen